# Stata: esttab only shows the last column of a foreach loop?

Tags: stata

I am trying to use the user-written command esttab (st0085_2) to give me a table of regression estimates. My code below only gives the last column (consumption). How can I change it so that each column is a different dependant variable from the list 'outcomelist'?

```
global outcomelist assets_total output_total expense_total profit_total self_empl income_dep hours_self_age16_65 hours_outside_age16_65 consumption 

foreach var of global outcomelist {
xi: reg `var' i.paire if samplemodel==1 & treatment==1, cluster(demi_paire)
est store est_`var'
global estimates1 est_`var'
}
esttab $estimates1, b(2) se(2) r2 obslast
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this in a comment earlier, but I think it constitutes an answer to you question:

It looks like you're writing over the macro every loop, so it will only store the last one.

Maybe try changing `` global estimates1 est_`var' `` to `` global estimates1 $estimates1 est_`var' ``. That way you are adding to the global rather than overwriting it.

I also would suggest you use local macros rather than globals in general.

The way I would code what you have done is as follows:

```
local outcomelist assets_total output_total expense_total profit_total self_empl income_dep hours_self_age16_65 hours_outside_age16_65 consumption 

// reset estimates1 local to empty just in case
local estimates1
foreach var in `outcomelist' {
xi: reg `var' i.paire if samplemodel==1 & treatment==1, cluster(demi_paire)
est store est_`var'
local estimates1 `estimates1' est_`var'
}
esttab `estimates1', b(2) se(2) r2 obslast
```